# Firebase : query all the chat rooms my user is involved in

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a Collection `message` which contains both a document (representing the chat room) and a nested collection which contains all the messages of that conversation.

[image]

Now I'd like to request all the documents (chat rooms) in which my user is involved. So if one of the `id1` or `id2` fields in the `users` map is equal to my user id, I collect that document.

I've noticed that I can't use array queries as I'm using maps and not arrays.

So I don't know what would be the best approach to proceed to that query.

```dart
Stream<List<ChatRoom>> getChatRooms(String userId) {
final messageCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages');
// var query = messagesCollection.where('users' in [userId])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See Frank's comment below:** The best solution is to "use an array of user IDs (`userIDs: ["ABCDEF", "GHIJKL"]`) and an [`array-contains`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) condition. In this use-case it seems that would save on the number of needed indexes (and thus on the cost of storage)".

If you really need to keep the map for other reasons, you can very well have the two fields in the doc. It's not a problem to duplicate the data.

---

If the value you assign to each userId in the map does not have to be meaningful, you can assign a Boolean value of `true` and then query as follows:

```
final messageCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages');
messageCollection.where('users.id1', isEqualTo: true)
  .get()
  .then(...);
```

---

So, your map will look like:

```
users
  id1: true
  id2: true
```

---

**Clarification:**

The idea is to use the user ids as keys and have a value of `true`. Let's imagine two users with the following ids: "ABCDEF" and "GHIJKL"

Instead of having a map like

```
users
  id1: "ABCDEF"
  id2: "GHIJKL"
```

you could have it as follows:

```
users
  ABCDEF: true
  GHIJKL: true
```

Note that you could very well have the two maps in the doc, if for some reason you really need to keep the first map.

Comment: Uhm..I don't get it :/ The ids in the map represent the id of the two interlocutors of that chat room. I don't understand why I would change them to boolean types

Comment: See the update "Clarification". Note that if you only have two users you could very well have an extra field of type Array that contains the ids of those two users.

Comment: Oh I see. So if this is the best way to do it, does it mean that in firestore it is not possible to query over a map ? Is it because there is no such thing as OR in noSQL databases ?

Comment: You can query as shown in my answer. In other words you need to know the map's keys.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant over the values of a map. Thank you !

Comment: If you have **only two users** you could join two queries: one that queries for users.id1 = "ABCDEF" and one that queries for users.id2 = "ABCDEF" but this is less efficient than what I propose.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Why don't you use an **array** of user IDs (`userIDs: ["ABCDEF", "GHIJKL"]`) and an [`array-contains` condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership)? In this use-case it seems that would save on the number of needed indexes (and thus on the cost of storage).

Comment: I haven't found any doc on array-contains for flutter :/

Comment: See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20489